# I am coding in Notepad but I cannot save because there is no file extension" (*.*)" after " All Files"

Tags: html, save, notepad

I am coding in Notepad and unable to save the file and then launch it into a web browser because instead of "All Files (*.*)" appearing when I select "save as" all I can see is "All Files" without the (*.*) suffix.  Can you please help I am a novice coder and 'stumped'.  Thanks.

I have undertaken multiple Google searches and found various videos on You Tube but they all only have "All Files (*.*)" as a "Save As" option.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose "Save As", just type "filename.html" manually. It should save it as an html file that your default browser will load. The file's icon should become that of your default browser (i.e. Chrome or Edge).

This not only works for Notepad, but also new blank files you create inside your working folder when using code editors such as VS Code, Sublime Text, Atom... etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestion "filename.html" before posting my question but the browser won't load it.  It did work on my previous laptop and converted it into the Chrome icon as you mentioned but it's not doing it on this pc. I appreciate your response - most kind. Is it normal for the "All Files" save as option not to have the (*. *) suffix?

Comment: @Fergie, strange. What you can do is find Encoding option below in the 'save as' box, and select 'UTF-8' from the dropdown menu. Try it with typing filename.html manually.

Comment: OK great thanks Haley A I'll try it in the morning - going to bed now it's late in England (UK). Will revert tomorrow.

Comment: UTF-8 didnt work either (sob).  Should "All Files" have the suffix (*.*) and if so, why would it be missing (weird) and how could it be remedied?

Comment: Try to type "filename.html" with quotation marks in the Save As box. This should force it to change extension.

Comment: Sadly it didn't Haley A.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Are you capable of renaming the file extension after you save it as .txt?

Comment: Haley A - problem solved - asked Microsoft - the file suffix should have been dot htm not dot html.  It then converts. Thank you for your help it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you have to type the name of the file and the file format. With notepad the only default formats are all for text.
After you save the file and open it, the default application for opening '.html' files will launch.

As for the (.*) after "All files", my notepad does not show the suffix either. It works the same anyway